# Application bundle Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, bundle

I had a working application bundle on Mac OS X Tiger. I was easily able to just replace the jar file and everything worked as i made changes. I take that app bundle now, and when it is on Leopard, I get the error message along the lines of "Cannot open this application because it is not supported on this architecture".

I assume this is because Tiger is 32-bit and Leopard is 64-bit. Is there a way to make this same app bundle work on Leopard? Or do I have to make an entirely new one? I am not a Mac guy, so am limited in what to do from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help you with the error message, but if you are using Eclipse you can simply run export to .app to create a new one.

At least that's possible in the new version of Eclipse(Ganymede) like this:

*Export->Other->Mac OS X application bundle*

**Step 1**:

*(Select Export..)*

[alt text http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/492/bildschirmfoto20090921ug.png](http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/492/bildschirmfoto20090921ug.png)

**Step 2**:

[alt text http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/8741/bildschirmfoto20090921u.png](http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/8741/bildschirmfoto20090921u.png)

Comment: I am using Galileo currently (Cocoa). I do not know if that feature is availble on here. I usually just exported as Runnable JAR and plugged it into the bundle. How do you export as .app? Or can you provide a link on how to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I did not know you could export this way and it works. I just had to enable the checkbox that said to load in 32-bit mode.