# Using Apple's Jar Bundler on a .jar that accesses files

Tags: java, file, jar, io

I have a large-ish project that contains one class that reads from a file (I have enclosed an SSCCE below). Everything works as it should. However, when I use either the Apple Jar Bundler or Eclipse's "Export to Mac OS X Application command" (following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455779/732016)), it doesn't work, and I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

I am trying to find out why I get this `FileNotFoundException`and how I can prevent it. My guess is that Eclipse is using its own classloader or something and that said classloader is not being properly invoked in the exported `jar` and hence the `app`.

SSCCE: The following code works when run from Eclipse, but not from a `.app`, `java -jar`, or even from the `java readfromfile.ReadFromFile` executed from the `bin` directory.

In *ReadFromFile.java*:

```
package readfromfile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ReadFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "src/readfromfile/file.txt";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(
                    new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(line));
            }
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOexception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In *file.txt*:

```
I am text
```

Comment: *"a .jar that accesses files"* Is the resource included ***inside*** the Jar?  If so, a `File` cannot be used to access it, instead use an `URL`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes, it's located inside the `.jar`. No, nothing writes to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the Jar Bundle maybe the `src/...` path does not exist.

Why don't you put the file as packages resource and you read it with:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(ReadFromFile.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
```

Naturally you have to put the file "file.txt" in the same package of your class.

Comment: *"packages resource"*  I generally refer to it as an 'embedded application resource'.  ( I'm trying to start a trend.  ;) *"Naturally you have to put the file "file.txt" in the same package of your class."*  I generally find it safer to refer to the resource by 'full path from the root of the class-path'.  In this case that might be along the lines of `"/readfromfile/file.txt"`.  +1 for recognizing that this resource might not be accessible as a `File`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson you are right, but I wanted to suggest a very simple solution to start with, however I vote your comment!

Comment: So, would `file.txt` be located in the same directory as `ReadFromFile.java`? Is that what you mean by "in the same package of your class"?